# Javascript automatically save pdf to a location?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am using the code below that prints a pdf with text from a session. Is there a way to have it just save to a location instead without printing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
     function printTextBox() {
         var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
         var windowName = 'Print' + new Date().getTime();
         var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');
         printWindow.document.write('Last Name:<%= Session("DoctorLastName") %>');
         printWindow.document.close();
         printWindow.focus();
         printWindow.print();
         printWindow.close();
     }
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: You can get the download popup by adding a content disposition header, but as to where, or if, the user decides to save it, is not up to you.

Comment: @adeneo He's doing this client-side, you can't mess with headers there. Basically he's generating PDF by using the browser's printing feature.

Comment: The usual way you handle this is by using a PDF generating library on the server. In fact, ".NET HTML to PDF libraries" are a veritable cottage industry.

Comment: Ya I thought there would be an easy way to do this not involving the user

Comment: Try [GitHub page for jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). Here is a [live demo](http://jspdf.com/#)

Comment: is this something that is free?

Comment: @millimoose - generating pdf's on the clientside with `window.print`. Good one, made my day.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, you cannot force the user to download the file to a particular location.

As you pointed out, the site visitor's browser will generally want to render the file, but if you specify server-side the MIME type to something like 'octet-stream' to indicate a binary file, it should instead prompt the user to download the file.

Making the browser download a file is discussed in general here: [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

If you tell us what server-side framework you're using we may be able to be more helpful.

Comment: I basically want to take the session data and generate a pdf and save it to a network location in the background when a user clicks the finish button.

Comment: Is the network location that you want to save to accessible to the browser or to the web server?

Comment: Yes, It is on the webserver

Comment: I see.  In that case, you need to process all this data server-side, or at the very least, post it to the server using AJAX.  You can then use your server-side framework to save the data to a network location.

The way you phrased the question, it sounded like you're trying to do it in the browser.